# An isomorphism between $U(13)$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism

I'm first asked to show that the groups $U(13)$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ are cyclic, and then to find an isomorphism between them. We can see that $U(13)= \langle 2 \rangle$ and  $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_4 = \langle (1,1) \rangle$.

I'm having an issue finding an isomorphism between the groups, I know it exists because their both finite cyclic groups of order 12. A thought I had was $\varphi:U(13) \rightarrow  \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ defined by $\varphi(n) = (1,1)^n$.

I think this works because it maps to a generator and because $1 \leq n \leq 12$ and  $|\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_4| = 12$, it definitely "hits" all elements.

Any guidance is very appreciated.

Comment: I think you are doing it right in sprit.  Just map $2$ to $(1,1)$ and extend by powers.

Comment: Note:  your $\varphi$ maps $2$ to $(2,2)$ which is NOT a generator.  You are writing $(1,1)^n$ when you should be thinking $n(1,1)$.

Comment: I know this sounds stupid but what do you mean map 2 to (1,1)?

Comment: Set $\varphi(2) = (1,1)$.  Since $2$ generates $U(13)$, this specifies a unique homomorphism (which will then be iso).  So, $\varphi(2^k) = k(1,1)$.

Comment: So the isomorphism would be $\varphi(2^n) = n(1,1)$ or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: No, you understand.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You can also answer your own question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $\varphi(n) = (1,1)^n$ is not quite an isomorphism, and also because the codomain is $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ it's better to think of $(1,1)^n$ as $n(1,1)$ (additively).

To fix it we would like to map a generator to a generator, and because $U(13) = \langle 2 \rangle$ and  $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_4 = \langle (1,1) \rangle$, so define $\varphi(2^n) = n(1,1)$.